# How can I use COUNTIFS to compare different date formats?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to calculate this for a column.

```
=countifs(another_sheet!E:E, A2,
   datevalue(another_sheet!A:A),datevalue(B2))
```

`another_sheet!A:A` has timestamps that look like `4/23/2023 14:13:43`
Whereas column B has values that look like `4/23/2023`.

How would you suggest managing this so that I can compare properly? I'm looking for the date matches (don't care about the timestamp itself).

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear.  You wrote  *"I'm trying to calculate this for a column"* but your example formula includes two columns, not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for the date matches  (don't care about the timestamp itself).

If you want to use [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) to count all the rows where both conditions are matched and you want to ignore times, then [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) should be applied to **all** the values, and the formula should also be wrapped in [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   COUNTIFS(DATEVALUE(another_sheet!E:E), DATEVALUE(A2), 
            DATEVALUE(another_sheet!A:A), DATEVALUE(B2)))
```